# How does this return the correct output?

Tags: java, string, equals

```
public int scoreUp(String[] key, String[] answers) {
  int score = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < key.length; i++) {
    if (key[i] == answers[i])
      score += 4;
    else if (answers[i] != "?" && answers[i] != key[i])
      score--;
  }
  return score;
}
```

This works on http://codingbat.com/prob/p180365 but it uses == to compare Strings instead of the equals method? How come?

Comment: It is not a compile error...

Comment: there should not be a compilation error - it just won't give you the right results because it compares the references (i.e pointers), not the content itself

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean 'compile'. I meant how does the method process the input and produces the correct output if it is comparing the object addresses and not the strings? 
You can test it yourself, copy the above code and paste it in the link I provided.

Answer (score 1):

> How does this **return** the correct output?

If both the `key` array and the `answer` array uses *interned* strings, then `==` is valid for comparison.

It is a dangerous assumption to make, so programmers should *always* use `equals()` for comparing strings, even if *interned* is guaranteed, because such guarantee may disappear in the future, and the the subtle implicit assumption may be overlooked. Always using `equals()` is futureproofing the code.

Answer (score 0):

`if (key[i] == answers[i])` in a valid reference comparing between 2 strings,

there is no reason for the compiler to complain, in fact that can be a logically way to check if objects are the same.

if that is the right way to compare string is another question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean 'compile'. I meant how does the method process the input and produces the correct output if it is comparing the object addresses and not the strings? 
You can test it yourself, copy the above code and paste it in the link I provided.